# how array hashcode() is calculated in java. Implementation of hashcode() in case of Array

Tags: java

`int[] i={1,2,3}` .equals `int i1[]={1,2,3}` and have different `hashcode()`. When I looked into the details it calls native `hashCode()` want to know how array hashcode is implemented.

Comment: Perhaps you really want to look at [java.util.Arrays.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals-int:A-int:A-)

Comment: `hashCode` returns different values for these two objects because they are stored in different chunks of memory, so despite holding similar content, they are different objects.  See [this answer](/a/13387787/2487517)

Answer (score 1):

The integer returned by the HashCode is different for both matrices because it is the object pointer value

```
System.out.println(i.hashCode()); // return 865113938
System.out.println(i1.hashCode()); // return 1442407170
```

`Arrays.hashCode` method returns a hash code based on the contents of the specified array and as the contents of the two arrays are equal return the same value

```
System.out.println(Arrays.hashCode(i)); // return 30817
System.out.println(Arrays.hashCode(i1));// return 30817
```

And if you want to compare two arrays could use [Arrays.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals-int:A-int:A-)

```
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(i, i1));//return true same content
```

Comment: The default hashcode is not inherently "the object pointer value". Objects can move around, but the hashcode does not change. It is, in some common JVMs a portion of the object's address is used to generate a hash. That's not the same as it being "the object pointer value". Even when the hashcode happens to match the bit pattern of one of the layers of pointers to an object, it's not useful to think of the hash as being a pointer value.

Comment: I was not looking for this        I know Arrays use the below code, so  here in your code you are using the Arrays hashcode. I want to understand how the normal arrays hashcode is calculated not the one in utl package                                                      public static int hashCode(int a[]) {
        if (a == null)
            return 0;

        int result = 1;
        for (int element : a)
            result = 31 * result + element;

        return result;
    }